# How to fail Ajax request in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-post

When user clicks a specific item, I use [jQuery's post method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to update something in the database:

```
$.post("/posts/" + post_id + "/update_something", 
       { some_param: some_value }, 
       success_handler);
```

where `update_something` looks like this:

```
def update_something
  post = Post.find(params[:id])
  post.update_attributes(:some_field => params[:some_param])
  render :nothing => true
end
```

The problem is if `update_attributes` fails, the request still succeeds and `success_handler` is executed.

How could I cause the request to fail when `update_attributes` fails such that `success_handler` won't be executed?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can either do `render :status => 400` (or some other error code) in Rails, which will trigger the `error` callback of `$.ajax()`, or you can render some JSON with an error message:

`render :json => { :success => false }`

Then in your `success_handler` function you would:

```
function success_handler (response) {
    if (response.success) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Edit:

Oh, and `update_attributes` returns false when it fails. So you can render your response based on that.

Edit 2 years later:

After a couple years and seeing that this has a few upvotes, I'd highly recommend using the `status: 400` method instead of rendering `200`. It's what the `error` handler in AJAX requests are for, and should be used that way.

Answer (score 6):

Well, you have to add an error handler, and give it an error to handle. So, in your JavaScript:

```
$.post( "/posts/" + post_id + "/update_something",
        { some_param : some_value }
      )
  .done( successHandler )
  .fail( errorHandler )      // define errorHandler somewhere, obviously
;
```

And in Rails:

```
def update_something
  post    = Post.find params[ :id ]

  success = post.update_attributes :some_field => params[ :some_param ]

  head success ? :ok : :internal_server_error
end
```

**Note:** `500` may or may not be the appropriate error code here—choose whichever among the [400s and 500s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't familiar with jQuery's `success` and `error` methods. Tried to look for docs but no success. Could you provide a pointer please?

Comment: +1 You could also just return a success/fail header. Your last line in Rails would look like `head success ? :ok : :internal_server_error`, where `head :ok` will return status 200, and `head :internal_server_error` will return status 500.

Comment: Misha: `post`, `get`, and `ajax` return a jqXHR object which is (poorly) [documented here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR). Reading that closer I noticed that `error` and `success` are deprecated and now you should use [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)'s `done` and `fail`. I've updated my code to reflect this, as well as incorporate @gg_s's advice, which is a good tip.